# Convert string to date

Tags: java, datetime, date

I have string of format 01-Jan-11 and I need to parse it to a Date in the format of 01-Jan-11.
Problem is when I try to do that always I got out put some thing like below.
Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2011

Can some one pls help me to do that?

> try {
>
> ```
>  String str_date="11-Jan-11";
>  DateFormat formatter ; 
>  Date date ; 
>       formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
>           date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);    
>            System.out.println("Today is " +date);
> } catch (ParseException e)
>
> {System.out.println("Exception :"+e);    }    
>      }
> ```

Time Zone is GMT+05:30 Kalkata

Comment: Publish your code, pls. And your time zone)

Comment: And your problem is? You are parsing January 1st, 2011 and get January 1st, 2011. What are you expecting?

Comment: problem is it is in the format of Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2011. But I am expecting in the Date in the format 01-Jan-11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that `parse` converts a string to a date. Your issue that you're taking the date and sending it to `println`, which essentially calls its `toString`, which has all the other stuff that you don't want (seconds, GMT offset, etc). Since you already have a formatter configured to your needs, simply use its `format` method:

```
System.out.println("Today is " + formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: The only actual answer to the question (+1)

Comment: There seems to be a trend on SO to just post a link to some docs and call it an answer.

Comment: forgive us for wanting users to better themselves by reading documentation rather than providing answers they can just cut and paste.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

The SimpleDateFormat class is what you want, check out this example here:

http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/CalendarExample.shtml